# Can Cordova retrieve the "id" attribute of button that triggered "click" event?

Tags: cordova

As something about Cordova clearly disables or renders-moot the **OnClick** attribute a button can have - I was finally able (after a ton of Googling) to use the following syntax to have a function that will activate every time there is a click event, no matter where on the page it is - using the following syntax:

```
document.addEventListener("click", on_the_click, false);
```

This invokes the following function:

```
function on_the_click ( )
{
  // Not sure what to do here
}
```

The problem is - as the comment clearly indicates, I'm not quite sure what to do next. For me to use this function as a replacement for what was lost when Cordova decided to disable or render-moot the button's **OnClick** attribute, I'd have to be able to retrieve at least the **id** attribute of the element that was clicked to trigger the event - thereby calling the appropriate function if it was indeed one of the three buttons that used to have an **OnClick** attribute, and returning to the calling program without doing anything if the element in question isn't one of those three buttons.

And here's the thing --- no amount of Googling is giving me the answers as to how I am to retrieve the **id** attribute of the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question, I **finally** figured out the answer -- or more accurately, I figured out I'd try one thing I hadn't previously thought of - and it worked both in the browser and in Android (the two platforms on which I am currently able to check).

Instead of adding the event listener to the entire document, I now add a separate event listener to each of the three relevant buttons - and I do this with the following syntax:

```
document.getElementById('button_calculate').addEventListener("click", process_the_daily_leson, false);
document.getElementById('button_maxline').addEventListener("click", process_the_drill, false);
document.getElementById('button_clear').addEventListener("click", make_all_clear, false);
```

That is - instead of using the **addEventListener** method of the document as a whole, I use the **addEventListener** method of the button itself.